# Posting on Octopress

Tags: octopress

I recently started looking for a solution to get ruby 'on the rails' for using with Octopress, due the fact I had issues with working with Ruby/Passenger/Apache I decided to host my Octopress site on Github pages.

Now I've got my own octopress running but I'm running into issues because I'm new with Github AND Octopress - maybe someone can help me out?

I have a:

- Master branch
- Source branch

This is what I see:

```
User@WKS-021 ~/octopress $ git remote -v
octopress   git://github.com/imathis/octopress.git (fetch)
octopress   git://github.com/imathis/octopress.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/xxxxx/xxxxx.github.com.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/xxxxx/xxxxx.github.com.git (push)
```

And:

```
User@WKS-021 ~/octopress $ git branch
* source
```

For now I imported the theme(s) I liked but how can I deploy the posts? For example from the Octopress documentation I can do:

```
rake new_post["Hello Octopress"]
# Creates source/_posts/2012-01-30-Hello-Octopress.markdown
```

I can see this in (after rake generate/deploy)

~/octopress/source/_posts (local)

But even after:

```
$rake generate
$git add .
$git commit -m "Initial blog post." 
$git push origin source
$rake deploy
```

I can't do anything with it, when I fill in the browser - I constantly get a 404 page error

http://xxxxx.nl/blog/2012/01/30/Hello-Octopress

What am I doing wrong AND are the posts coming on the frontpage (index.html) or? Even tried to make pages but same issue.

Comment: Have you make things done? I face the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

From [github pages help](https://help.github.com/articles/should-i-rename-username-github-com-repositories-to-username-github-io), maybe you need to rename your repo to `username.github.io`.